# Protobuf message on subdirestory CMake Linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, protobuf-c

need to generate and connect the message.proto file to the unit tests. CMake throws an error:`fatal error: protobuf/message.pb.h: not found #include <protobuf/message.pb.h>`
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0016 NEW)

project(protobuf_parser VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "Разбор потока length-prefixed Protobuf сообщений на C++")

include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(test)
```

CMakeLists.txt /src/protobuf:

```
include(FindProtobuf)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS message.proto)

add_library(protobuf ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
target_link_libraries(protobuf INTERFACE ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES})
```

CMakeLists.txt /test:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(Example Test_Helpers.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Example PUBLIC
    gtest_main
    protobuf_parser
    protobuf ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}
    )
add_test(
    NAME Example
    COMMAND Example
    )
```

I searched for information on the Internet, but I couldn't find it

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. Also in unit tests I would not expect any RPC code. What I would expect is some C++ code testing against an abstract base class of which later there will be an implementation using gRPC. And then you have left the unit test phase and are doing the first of  integration tests (making actual RPC calls)

Comment: Please, edit the question post and make the **error message** to be **complete**: it should include not only the name of the missed file, but also the name of the file which is compiled. See e.g. [that FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) about why a complete error message is important.